# Как исправить баги?

Tags: c++, классы, типы-данных

**Вот мой код:**

```
#include <iostream>
struct player{
    public:
    char *name;
    player* next;
    player(player&,char *);
    player* getnext();
    ~player();
};
player::player(player& next_,char *nm){
    name = nm;
    next = &next_;
};
player* player::getnext(){
    return next;
};
player::~player(){
    delete name;
    delete next;
};
struct lobby{
    public:
    player* first;
    player* last;
    lobby(player&);
    void delfirst();
    void addlast(char*);
    ~lobby();
};
lobby::lobby(player& waiting){
    first = &waiting;
    last = &waiting;
};
void lobby::delfirst(){
    if(first == last){
        std::cout << "\n";
    }else{
        player* p = last;
        player* p_pr;
        while (p != first){
            p_pr = p;
            p = (*p).getnext();
        };
        std::cout << p <<"\n";
        delete p;
        first = p_pr;
        delete p_pr;
    };
};
void lobby::addlast(char *name){
    player p((&(*last)),name);
    last = &p;
}
lobby::~lobby(){
    delete first;
    delete last;
};
int main(){
    std::cout << "Good";
    return 0;
```

**А вот баги:**

```
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor-xqwETs/sol.cpp: In member function 'void lobby::addlast(char*)':
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor-xqwETs/sol.cpp:51:26: error: no matching function for call to 'player::player(player*, char*&)'
   51 |  player p((&(*last)),name);
      |                          ^
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor-xqwETs/sol.cpp:10:1: note: candidate: 'player::player(player&, char*)'
   10 | player::player(player& next_,char *nm){
      | ^~~~~~
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor-xqwETs/sol.cpp:10:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'player*' to 'player&'
   10 | player::player(player& next_,char *nm){
      |                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor-xqwETs/sol.cpp:2:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr player::player(const player&)'
    2 | struct player{
      |        ^~~~~~
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor-xqwETs/sol.cpp:2:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
]
```

Comment: player p(((*last)), name); исправьте на это

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не баги, а синтаксические ошибки :)

```
player p((&(*last)),name);
```

Что такое `last`?

```
player* last;
```

Значит, тип `*last` — `player&`.

Тип `&(*last)`, соответственно, `player*`.

У вас же конструктор описан как

```
player::player(player& next_,char *nm){
```

Т.е. нужна ссылка, вы передаете указатель... Вот и все.

P.S. Что-то мне кажется, что в этом коде это не последняя ошибка, но это уже другой вопрос...

Comment: Тип `*last` - `player` ([выражения не бывают ссылками](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1)). То, что `decltype` считает его `player &` - это его проблемы (он приписывает `&` к типам lvalue). Простите мое занудство. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну, главное, что это, как я понимаю (теперь уже ни в чем не уверен) lvalue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,   принципиально,  разыменованный указатель  есть обращение к объекту, что трактуется как другое имя объекта. Это и есть ссылка

Comment: @ARHovsepyan По смыслу может и так, но стандарт говорит, что там не ссылка: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-1

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  Спасибо за ссылку, прочту как нибудь. Но логично, что по факту  _ да(если, как вы сказали, занудствовать) , если рассуждать с точки зрения компилятора, то   это не ссылка,  а прямое обращение к объекту.